Definition of Candela and Lumen
I have been trying to understand the significance of the number $685$ in the definition of lumen: 1 lumen is the luminous flux emitted by a $1/685$ Watt monochromatic source of $555$ nm. I have read that 1 candela ($1\ candela = 1\ lumen/steradian$) is the luminous intensity of a candle.
So the total luminous flux emitted by a candle should be $4\pi$ lumen.
Therefore it follows that a $555$ nm monochromatic source of power $4\pi /685$ Watt should produce the same brightness as that of a candle. Is my analysis correct? If not, please explain the significance of the number 685. Thanks.

Seems totally correct... (if the monochromatic source in your example is omnidirectional).

683 not 685?  a lumen corresponds to an amount of light ... like 1000 photons of green  is x lumens.  But it may take 2x photons to produce the same lumens for a different color. And if your source is a spectrum a weighted average is required to get the lumens.

From NIST:

This constant, Kcd, is equal to 683 lumens per watt—a value that makes the modern candela roughly equivalent to the previously defined candela. Roughly speaking, 1/683 watt per steradian is the amount of power needed to generate a candle’s brightness.

I think it was to be inferred, but the last sentence from the quote above should be read as "1/683 watt per steradian is the amount of power of a 540nm source needed to generate a candle's brightness."
The short answer to your question is that the value of 683 was selected so that the 'new' definition of the Candela (based on a single wavelength) seamlessly matched the 'old' definition (based on a broader spectrum such as an incandescent filament).
And therefore: yes, your understanding/analysis is correct.

Long answer:
I recommend reading the entire article from NIST, but the gist is that the definition of the Candela changed, and this change led to defining the constant Kcd = 683 lm/W.
The Candela used to be defined using a source with a broad spectral output (literally a candle in the 1800s, then to an incandescent filament - roughly a blackbody - in the early-mid 1900s), but these broad sources were harder to keep constant/stable.  Then, in 1979, after the invention of lasers, the definition of the Candela was changed to be tied to a specific individual wavelength, presumably so the source generating that light was more stable.
Based on the wavelength chosen during this change in definition, a scale factor was required such that this new definition still produces a 'candle' with the same 'brightness' as the old (literal) candles used in the old definitions.
(FWIW, in 1979 the Candela was defined using 540nm and a constant Kcd ~= 683, rather than 555nm and 685.  I presume that 685 would be the factor needed for 555nm to be equivalent to the older, broader sources.  Perhaps somewhere there is a record of why 540nm was specifically chosen, and therefore why Kcd had to be 683.)
